# How can I display tabledata with Java Stored Procedure?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, java-stored-procedures

Currently, I'm testing some `stored procedures` in `JAVA` on `oracle db`, so I tried to display all the emp entities.

So my question is how can I display a whole table throught a java stored procedure?

This is what i tried:

```
create or replace and compile java source named getEMP
as
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Example{
    public static void showEmp() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
            ResultSet rs;
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put("user", "user");
            p.put("password","password");
            String strCon = "Connection String";

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"); 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(strCon, p);

            Statement stmt;

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(strCon, p);
            String query =
                    "select empno, ename, deptno, sal, comm " +
                    "from emp";

            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        //Display the ResultSet
    }
}
```

My problem in this methode is that i can't use `System.out.println("");`. It just displays nothing after this:

```
create or replace procedure showEmp
as language java name 'Example.showEmp()';

exec showEmp;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I never knew there was something called java stored procedures !

Comment: hint: a stored procedure runs in the database. Not in your application.

Comment: I have never used Java stored procedure, but maybe you can use `dbms_output` or you return a result set that you can select from? However that should all be documented in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that server output is enabled and also to redirect java output to it. In SQL*PLus you can accomplish that with the following two statements:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> call dbms_java.set_output(20000);
```

The number 20000 is the maximum buffer size, same as in `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

After this if you run `exec showEmp;` you should be able to see the results of a `System.out.println()` call being printed out.