# stored procedure is not displaying results in jsp

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to execute results from my stored procedure and it is not displaying anything. I have played around with sql syntax query and nothing worked...when I do a normal select statement I get results from my tables, but so far nothing worked with my stored procedure...what am I not getting results ?

I am using sql-server by the way

```
   <%        
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://....";
    String username = "something";
     String password = "something";

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    CallableStatement cs;

    cs = conn.prepareCall("{ exec rptGetAssetbyLocation(?, ?,?,?,?,?) }");


    cs.setString(1, "name");
    cs.setString(2, "model");
    cs.setString(3, "serialNumber");

    cs.setString(4, "type");
    cs.setString(5, "condition");
    cs.setString(6, "note");

    try {
    cs.execute();
    out.println("Stored procedure completed successfully.<br>");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    out.println("The following error occurred: " + e + "<br>");
    }

    %>
```

edit:

ran a stacktrace

I am getting an error `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '{'.`

Comment: isnt it `executeQuery();`

Comment: that is a ResultSet method ? so I am missing a ResultSet here ?

Comment: sorry not executeQuery,it should be executeUpdate()...y arent u using preparedstatement?

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone he is calling a procedure . so need to use `executeQuery` . Also remember he is using `callable` statement

Comment: see if this link helps u http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/callablestatement-object-example.htm  ..never used callablestatement

Comment: in the example you provided me , it uses execute();

Comment: I've used this example...http://www.coderanch.com/t/279755/JSP/java/calling-stored-procedure-Jsp

Comment: interesting thing when I do "call" instead of "exec" I get "Procedure or function rptGetAssetbyLocation has too many arguments specified"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the output from the procedure to need to do something like this

`char val= ((OracleCallableStatement)cs).getCHAR(3)`

Remember [OracleCallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) is an interface which implements `CallableStatement, OraclePreparedStatement`

You can override its method to get the results from the callable statments

Also these examples would help you

[**1.how to display tabledata with java stored procedure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148008/how-can-i-display-tabledata-with-java-stored-procedure)

[**2.Stored procedure with Input/Output parms and a ResultSet**](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0120.html)

[**3.Java Stored procedures**](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/java-stored-procedures-in-java-db.html)

Hope this helps !!