# MYSQL Store Procedure like SQL SERvER with IF ELSE CONDITION

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
Create Procedure spText(IN Cust_Name longtext)

begin

   Declare

     @varWhere varchar(max)= '  WHERE Cust_No is not null ' + Char(13),
     @varSQL varchar(Max)

        SET @varSQL='select * form Customer_Dtls'


        if Cust_Name  is not null
            BEGIN

                 set @varWhere=@varWhere + ' and Custer_Nm like %Cust_Name%' + Char(13)
        end 

   EXEC (@varSQL + @varWhere)

end
```

in MySQL dont know how to do this i google it but not getting any answer please help me ......

i want that way if i pass customer name then i get as per customer name data if i pass null then i got all customer data

in sql server it work for me but how to do in mysql dont know because i am using jsp and backend is mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code it must be FROM and not form.

In MySQL this procedure works as intended

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `spText`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spText`(IN Cust_Name longtext)
BEGIN


    SET  @varWhere = '  WHERE Cust_No is not null ' ;
    SET @varSQL='select * FORM Customer_Dtls ';


        IF Cust_Name  is not null THEN
            set @varWhere= CONCAT(@varWhere, " and Custer_Nm like '%Cust_Name%'");
            END IF;
        SET @SQL= CONCAT(@varSQL , @varWhere);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECute stmt;
end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: sir one more how can to use this store procedure in JSP page resultSet please update me sir

Comment: see here https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0120.html  and here are more links to it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978212/stored-procedure-is-not-displaying-results-in

Comment: sir getting issue 

"Callable statments not supported"

MYCONNECTION IS 

 String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ;
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyNew_db" ;
          String uname="root" ;
          String pass="123456" ;

          Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
          con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pass);

Comment: Check please this small tutorial https://www.mysqltutorial.org/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-from-jdbc/  and as far as i can see it is the same only with some more explanation. If it still doesn't work, make a new question with your source code and we will find a solution

Answer (score 0):

nbk sir answer my question perfectly thank you